# Python subprocess fails in scripts: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'

Tags: python

I've been scouring forums for hours and can't seem to find a similar issue--could anyone help me understand why subprocess seems to work fine in IDLE but fails when I try to execute a script via the command line?

Here's an example of my code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output('notepad', shell=True)
```

In IDLE, Notepad immediately opens; when I run "python subtest.py" on the command line, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\test\subtest.py", line 1, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "C:\Python27\test\subprocess.py", line 8, in <module>
    test = subprocess.Popen(my_command, shell=True, stdout=out, stderr=err)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Popen'
```

It appears to be failing on the import statement--I also tried:

```
import subprocess
try:
    subprocess.check_output('notepad', shell=True)
except AttributeError as e:
    print e
```

It fails with the same error--it never gets to the try/except block.

Any suggestions would be most appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you have a file named `subprocess.py` on same path where `subtest.py` resides. Try to rename that file.

Comment: This can be a pretty baffling and frustrating error if you've never seen it before.

Comment: Thank you, @a_python_user! That was the problem! (And here I thought I was clever by trying to use my filenames to keep track of the different things I've been testing...)

Comment: Well, that's a logical plan, but as you've learned the hard way, it doesn't work out so well. ;)